# The service definition "monolog.logger.event" does not exist

Tags: symfony, monolog

I have created different channels for my monolog, while working with my app (dev and test environment) everything is fine, creates and writes into all logs but when execute my tests (unit test) I am getting the following error: "The service definition "monolog.logger.event" does not exist" 
I've dump my "ContainerBuilder $container" in "vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/LoggerChannelPass.php" and for some reason the monolog.logger.event does not exists, all the rest of my channels do exists: doctrine, request, security, etc...
I am pasting my monolog config corresponding to the channels:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['!event', '!snc_redis', '!doctrine', '!request', '!security']
        event:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_event.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['event']
        snc_redis:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_redis.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['snc_redis']
        doctrine:
            type:  stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_doctrine.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['doctrine']
        request:
            type:  stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_request.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['request']
        security:
            type:  stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_security.log"
            level:  debug
            channels: ['security']
```

Any clue how can I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happens because **web/app_test.php** and console have different debug flag, for example:

```
#web/app_test.php    
$kernel = new AppKernel('test', false);

#bin(app)/console
$kernel = new AppKernel('test', true);
```

In this situation web application cannot find the right cache container file.